# Sencha Local storage inserting issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a sencha code that will insert to my local storage but the problem after the value was inserted it shows empty value {} on the Weblocalstorage
Link for picture: http://i7.photobucket.com/albums/y283/eugene0014/LocalStorage%201_zpseh4mrlhn.png

Here's my Controller code:

```
SearchValue = {};
SearchValue.key = 1;
SearchValue.value = "TEST";

var WebStore = Ext.create('MPEXTJS1503.store.WebStore');
WebStore.add(SearchValue);
WebStore.sync();
```

Here's my Store

```
Ext.define('MPEXTJS1503.store.WebStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.WebStore',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage',
    'MPEXTJS1503.model.WebStoreModel'
],
config: {
    model: 'MPEXTJS1503.model.WebStoreModel',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'RecentSearch'
      }
    }
 });
```

Here's my Model Code:

```
Ext.define('MPEXTJS1503.model.WebStoreModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
alias: 'model.WebStoreModel',
config: {
    fields: [{
        name: 'key'
    }, {
        name: 'value'
    }]
    }
});
```

Comment: var WebStore = Ext.getStore('WebStore');

Answer (score 0):

Use Ext.getStore() then add record. It will work. You have to add store in app.js or controllers. 
 ex.

```
     In app.js
    stores:['MPEXTJS1503.store.WebStore']


     Then 
     var webStore = Ext.getStore('WebStore');
     webStore.add(SearchValue);
     webStore.sync();
```